# Ask about pointer and access memory in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, marshalling, dllimport, access-violation

I have a problem but i don't understand about it, i don't know root cause of problem.
I hame a small program and when run it on win 7 (64 bits) access violation exception occurs. This exception does not occur on winXP (32 bits).
After that, i change some code and access violation exception does not occur (both on win 7 and winxp).
I don't root cause of exception.
Code as bellow.
Code before ( access violation exception occurn on win 7).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct gpc_vertex
{
public float x;
public float y;
};

private ArrayList DoPolygonOperation()
{
IntPtr currentVertex = vertexList.vertexes;

gpc_vertex oVertext = new gpc_vertex();

for (int j = 0; j < vertexList.num_vertices; j++)
{
    PositionF pos = new PositionF();
    oVertext = (gpc_vertex)Marshal.PtrToStructure(currentVertex, typeof(gpc_vertex));
    //Access violation exception
    pos.X = oVertext.x;
    pos.Y = oVertext.y;
    Marshal.DestroyStructure(currentVertex, typeof(gpc_vertex));
    currentVertex = (IntPtr)((int)currentVertex.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(oVertext));

    posList.Add(pos);
}
}
```

Code after modify (access violation exception does not occur):

```
private ArrayList DoPolygonOperation()
{
 IntPtr currentVertex = vertexList.vertexes;

gpc_vertex oVertext = new gpc_vertex();
int currentOffset = 0; 
for (int j = 0; j < vertexList.num_vertices; j++)
{
 PositionF pos = new PositionF();
 oVertext = (gpc_vertex)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)(currentVertex.ToInt64() + currentOffset), typeof(gpc_vertex));
 pos.X = oVertext.x;
 pos.Y = oVertext.y;
 Marshal.DestroyStructure(currentVertex, typeof(gpc_vertex));
 currentOffset += Marshal.SizeOf(oVertext);

 posList.Add(pos);
}
}
```

Please help me to find root cause of access violation exception at before code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem may be in this line:

```
currentVertex = (IntPtr)((int)currentVertex.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(oVertext));
```

On a 64-bit operating system, you could be getting overflow when you cast the 64 bit value to a 32 bit int.

To determine if this is the case, put `checked` around it and test it to see if it throws an overflow exception:

```
checked
{
    currentVertex = (IntPtr)((int)currentVertex.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(oVertext));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Can you tell me detail about overflow when cast the 64 bit value to a 32 bit int

Comment: Well, if a 64 bit number has a value which is greater than `int.MaxValue` or less than `int.MinValue` then it won't fit inside a 32 bit int, so the extra bits will just be lost.

Comment: Thanls a lot, I understood.